# Error In google sheets with Golang

Tags: go, google-sheets

when i follow the steps from https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/go
and
run as go run quickstart.go

I got Error as below

2017/08/03 12:29:22 Unable to retrieve data from sheet. Get https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/14FXalPXVUHZ2SyNBUWJpfSzUSSimYYIR5mUU36r6_BQ/values/A%3AC?alt=json: oauth2: cannot fetch token: 401 Unauthorized
Response: {
  "error" : "unauthorized_client"
}
exit status 1

Comment: Yes .same error .Do yo have any idea.how to solve?

Comment: Code ran one time after that it stopped

Comment: Where can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

We have to delete credential file in our system because after 1 day or certain time access token of oauth2 protocol got expired.For new access token,you need to delete credential  file and run program again.